# Overloaded template function doesn't select the correct version for a specific type

Tags: c++

Situation is: I have a generic function but would like an altered version for a specific type.

I would instinctively write a `widget const& w` parameter to be able to accept any widget by reference, but that doesn't compile in that case, because the compiler ignored the specific overload (2) and used generic (1) instead. It does compile if I remove the const in the params of (2), why is that?

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YqPRQj)

```
struct widget {
    int widget_size;
};

// (1)
// compiler uses this instead of (2)
template <typename Arg>
int get_size(Arg && arg) {
   return arg.size;
}

// (2)
int get_size(widget const& arg) {
    return arg.widget_size;
}

int main() {
    widget w;
    get_size(w);
}
```

Comment: Overload (1) is a better match as it matches the argument exactly, while overload (2) requires a const-qualification conversion.

Comment: @iPherian Does my answer, *answers* your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because the compiler ignored the specific overload .

Please note that Version 2 is a better match as argument passed lacks `const` keyword and version 1 also lacks `const` keyword.

> that doesn't compile in that case.

`Widget` class doesn't have `size` member variable in it. It's got `widget_size` , which is causing compilation error.

```
int get_size(Arg && arg) {
   return arg.widget_size; // See this
}
```

> It does compile if I remove the const in the params of (2), why is that?

This is because `get_size(w);` started matching version 2, thereby omitting any need for compiler to check for `widget_size` in version 1.